# Stylecop vs FXcop

Tags: fxcop, stylecop

Has Stylecop superseded FXcop? 
Which product should we be using with Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580168/visual-studio-code-analysis-vs-stylecop-fxcop

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Stylecop is a style analysis tool that works at the source code level.  It exists primarily to provide a single common style that managed projects can use to remain consistent within the larger world of managed software.  It makes decisions regarding style primarily to avoid holy wars (after all, style is almost always an inherently subjective thing).  I don't think I've ever met someone who liked all of StyleCop's rules, but that's *ok*.  It means that StyleCop is a generally good compromise amongst the vast set of style guidelines that exist. (If stylecop's rules were highly customizable, beyond simply enabling/disabling them, it would defeat the entire purpose of the tool.)

FxCop, on the other hand, is a static analysis tool that works on the level of the managed assembly.  It can be given directions via attributes because it can see attributes on code elements, e.g..  It detects problems that can be seen on the "binary" level (as it were) as opposed to the syntactic level.

To answer your question, StyleCop doesn't supercede FxCop, and FxCop doesn't supercede stylecop.  They're two different tools with two different purposes that can both provide a real benefit for your code.

(AKA, I run with both.  :) )

---

A couple examples of the things one might detect vs. things the other might detect:

StyleCop violations might include warnings related to:  Whitespace, Formatting, Public method documentation via xml-comments, order of method definition within a class.

FxCop violations might include warning related to:  Globalization, tight coupling, cyclomatic complexity, potential null dereferences.

Comment: Yes, the previous answers comparing the two are wrong on all counts. StyleCop and FxCop perform two very different tasks, and it is worth investigating the value each provides on your codebase and why you should run them.

Comment: Agree that not all StyleCop rules are good, but as you say the ones you don't want can be disabled. We're using StyleCop - after disabling the plain stupid rules it's providing good value for us - at low cost..! Recommended. (note that we hated it at first glance..)

Comment: @stiank81:  Yeah, I think _everybody_ hates StyleCop at first.  After a little time, though, the benefits really establish themselves and it proves itself to be a _very_ useful tool for maintaining consistency in source.  :)

Answer (score 17):

stylecop works on your C# source code.  fxcop looks at your compiled code from any .net language.

Comment: So if you use Stylecop, can FXCop add any value?

Comment: Really, you're better off using FxCop.

Comment: At least for now, until it becomes more configurable. :)

Comment: It's unlikely that stylecop will become significantly more configurable.  A far more important feature for stylecop is the automatic correction of style violations.

Comment: we use Resharper to automagically make code conform to stylecop rules.  That alone makes it worth the purchase price.  And you get all the other benefits on top of that one.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative or a good complement to *FxCop/StyleCop* would be to use the commercial tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). With this tool one can **write Code Rule over LINQ Queries** [(namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default, these include *design*, *architecture*, *code quality*, *code evolution*, *naming conventions*, *dead code*, *.NET Fx usage*...

CQLinq is dedicated to write code rules that can be [verified live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx), or that can be [verified during build process and reported in an HTML/javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

The strength of CQLinq over FxCop or StyleCop, is that **it is straightforward to write a code rule**, and get *immediately* results. Facilities are proposed to browse matched code elements. Concretely this looks like that:

[image: CQLinq code rule]

Answer (score 6):

FXCop does static code analysis of your managed code assemblies. Think of it as finding issues that will cause problems at run-time or that will affect how the developer believes the code will run (unreachable code).

StyleCop analyzes the structure of you code from a text point of view. Think of this as issues that will affect your development and design experience (Formatting, naming conventions, documentation)

They are both VERY valuable tools and you should use both but they do focus on different problems.

Answer (score 5):

StyleCop performs source code analysis is not very configurable. It doesn't really do the same thing as FxCop, which analyzes the compiled code.

The wikipedia articles on these provide good summaries of the differences:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop