# Visual Studio 2010 code analysis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using code analysis tool of VS 2010..two things that i have noticed was not provided:

1. Proper casing of variable,method and properties names
2. xml comments for each method,event and other activities

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: Contrary to most of the answers so far, you *don't* need StyleCop for either of your problems.  See my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point - 2 can be address by Stylecop - [enter link description here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).  Assuming your using c#.

Answer (score 1):

FxCop does handle one of those things.  Are you sure you've turned on all of the rules?

Under the Microsoft.Naming FxCop rules you have rules such as CA1702: "Compound words should be cased correctly."

Missing XML comments is actually a compiler wanring (warning 1591).  I suspect you have to turn on XML documentation generation in the project for that to occur, though.  Under the build tab of your project properties, make sure the "Xml documentation file" checkbox is marked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any money to spend, I'd recommend [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). If you don't have any to spend, download the trial anyway and give it a go.  It'll highlight casing as you code in accordance with configurable rules.

[StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) will warn of public methods without sufficient comments.  There's a good answer on the difference between FXCop and StyleCop here: [Stylecop vs FXcop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884522/stylecop-vs-fxcop)

Answer (score 0):

Code analysis only checks for good coding practise such as remembering to dispose disposable objects etc

StyleCop will help address the other two scenarios you outlined above.