# Which are the differences between StyleCop and Code Analysis when talking about the rules of each?

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

Could you please tell me which are the differences between rules of StyleCop and Code Analysis ? Should it be used together or not ?

Thanks.

Comment: Code analysis was previously called FxCop, this answer should give you what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884522/stylecop-vs-fxcop

Comment: Code Analysis should be compared to FxCop, not StyleCop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Style cop essentially parses the file looking for formatting issues and other things that you could think of as "cosmetic".  Code analysis actually builds your code and inspects the compiled runtime  IL for characteristics about how it behaves when it runs and flag potential runtime problems.

So, they are complimentary, and you are perfectly fine to use them together.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer:

- stylecop: takes your **source code** as input and checks for potential **code style issues**. For instance: `using` directives are not alphabetically ordered...etc.
- fxcop (now code analysis): takes a **compiled assembly** as input and checks for potential issues related **to the executable/dll itself when it'll be executed**. For instance: in your class you have a member of type `IDisposable` that is not disposed properly.

However, there are some rules that are common to both tools, for instance rules related to naming convention for public exposed types.

Anyway, using both is a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

FxCop checks ***what is written***. It works over the compiled assembly.

StyleCop checks ***how it is written***. It works over the parsed source file, even without trying to compile it.

This leads to all the differences. For example, FxCop cannot check indentations, cause they are absent in a compiled assembly. And StyleCop cannot perform code-flow checks cause it doesn't know how your code is really being executed.