# how to Import fxcop file to stylecop

Tags: c#, fxcop, stylecop

I have one .fxcop rule file is there any way where i can import this file to Stylecop?

Please let me know the step by step approach for this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think that's possible as FxCop and StyleCop are completely different tools for different purposes. See [Stylecop vs FXcop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884522/stylecop-vs-fxcop)

Comment: Thanks... installed fxcop now and doing it with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rule you have in FxCop, it might be possible to port it to StyleCop (or Roslyn), but you can's simply import or combine these tools. The reason behind this is that FxCop inspects the compiled binaries, while StyleCop parses the actual source code.

If you update your question to include the purpose of the rule, we might be able help you with that.