# How to get FxCop for WinXP?

Tags: .net, fxcop, coding-style

I have Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010 installed.

Intended to use FxCop to check if the solution corresponds to the Microsoft Code Guides.

Now found out that FxCop is part of "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4"

Should I install this thing, even if I have Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

FxCop 10 can be run on WindowsXP (I have installed it on my XP box at work.) Having said that, I agree with Anuraj's comment - if you are using a version of VisualStudio 2010 that includes code analysis, using that is an easy place to start.  With a few exceptions, both VS and FxCop use the same rule set, so knowing one will help with the other.

Comment: Pedro. your answer is in contradiction with the GWLlosa one... I don't understand anymore what is the latest version XP compatible...

Comment: As Andrew Brown points out in his comment, the Windows 7 SDK can be installed on XP.  FxCop 10 is part of that SDK and will install and run on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Static code analysis enabled instead of FxCop. It include FxCop and more. More information can be get from this SO link

[Visual Studio Code Analysis vs StyleCop + FxCop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580168/visual-studio-code-analysis-vs-stylecop-fxcop)

Comment: thanks. However I don't know even FxCop, so I prefer do not have even "more".

Comment: I think Static code analysis is better option, because you will get the errors when ever you compile the application, if it is enabled ;)

Answer (score 0):

FxCop 1.36 is the last version that officially supports Windows XP. Essentially, it is part of the SDK.  The SDK in question ( WinSDK 7.0 (Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .Net Framework 3.5 SP1)) can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en).

Comment: thanks, but you should read the question more attentively. I require nothing but having latest version of FxCop under **WindowsXP**.

Comment: So, even if the download it "for Windows 7" I can install it on Windows XP?

Comment: Yes.  The [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements) clearly state that Windows XP is a supported operating system.  It's titled "Windows 7 SDK" because this release of the SDK supports _targeting_ Windows 7.  But it continues to support targeting downlevel operating systems, and you can develop your code using the SDK from any of the operating systems listed in the system requirements, as well.