# Visual Studio 2017 Code Analysis - What options are there?

Tags: code-analysis

After discovering the "Run code analysis on solution" option in visual studio 2017 I began looking for other similar tools, I found [Visual Studio Code Analysis vs StyleCop + FxCop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580168/visual-studio-code-analysis-vs-stylecop-fxcop) From here I've found out about StyleCop and then also found Web Accessibility Checker within NuGet by manualy searching through.

So this leads me to my question, Focusing on C#, .Net, HTML, CSS, JS and international web standards.

What other tools can be used to provide this kind of analysis / hinting / refactor suggestions or are there any extended rulesets?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the tool NDepend that integrates with Visual Studio 2017 (and also lower VS versions): https://www.ndepend.com/

See here its default rule-set, you'll find rules quite different from the VSCodeAnalysis (like rules about API Breaking Changes, OOP, Architecture or Code Coverage values check)
https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html

One other peculiarity of NDepend is that rules are just textual LINQ queries executed as-is (no compilation, no project, no assembly...). This makes it easy to adapt existing rules to your own need and create your custom rules:
https://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL

Also for each issue NDepend will estimate both the cost-to-fix and the cost-to-not-fix (technical-debt and annual interest). Those are actionable metrics for developers and managers:
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/technical-debt

Finally you can define a baseline and browse issues introduced since the baseline. This solves the usual problem of *thousands of issues found* by analyzers. You can first focus on new issues and then see if the many issues introduced a long time ago are worth fixing or not.

*Disclaimer: I work for NDepend*